# given a list of objects using C# push them to ravendb without knowing which ones already exist

Tags: batch-processing, ravendb

Given 1000 documents with a complex data structure. for e.g. a Car class that has three properties, Make and Model and one Id property.

What is the most efficient way in C# to push these documents to raven db (preferably in a batch) without having to query the raven collection individually to find which to update and which to insert. At the moment I have to going like so. Which is totally inefficient.
**note : _session is a *wrapper on the IDocumentSession* where Commit calls SaveChanges and Add calls Store**.

```
    private void PublishSalesToRaven(IEnumerable<Sale> sales)
    {
        var page = 0;
        const int total = 30;
        do
        {
            var paged = sales.Skip(page*total).Take(total);
            if (!paged.Any()) return;
            foreach (var sale in paged)
            {
                var current = sale;
                var existing = _session.Query<Sale>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == current.Id);
                if (existing != null)
                    existing = current;
                else
                    _session.Add(current);
            }
            _session.Commit();
            page++;
        } while (true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sample doesn't work at all. The main problem is that you cannot just switch out the references and expect RavenDB to recognize that:

```
if (existing != null)
    existing = current;
```

Instead you have to update each property one-by-one:

```
existing.Model = current.Model;
existing.Make = current.Model;
```

This is the way you can facilitate change-tracking in RavenDB and many other frameworks (e.g. NHibernate). If you want to avoid writing this uinteresting piece of code I recommend to use AutoMapper:

```
existing = Mapper.Map<Sale>(current, existing);
```

Another problem with your code is that you use Session.Query where you should use Session.Load. *Remember: If you query for a document by its id, you will always want to use Load!*
The main difference is that one uses the local cache and the other not (the same applies to the equivalent NHibernate methods).

Ok, so now I can answer your question:
If I understand you correctly you want to save a bunch of Sale-instances to your database while they should either be added if they didn't exist or updated if they existed. Right?
One way is to correct your sample code with the hints above and let it work. However that will issue one unnecessary request (Session.Load(existingId)) for each iteration. You can easily avoid that if you setup an index that selects all the Ids of all documents inside your Sales-collection. Before you then loop through your items you can load all the existing Ids.

However, I would like to know what you actually want to do. What is your domain/use-case?

Comment: Thank you Daniel for those pointers. Very useful. My use case is to run a process periodically that polls a SQL server table and pushes updates/inserts to Raven. I already have a mechanism that identifies changed/new records in the sql server table since the last update to Raven (via a LastModified datetime property on the Car class).

Comment: Just keep in mind that entirely relying on date-fields is somewhat dangerous when it comes to syncing between two databases on different server, because system-time might change on one of the server... Btw, if you found my response useful, you can also mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your session code doesn't seem to track with the RavenDB api (we don't have `Add` or `Commit`).
Here is how you do this in RavenDB

```
private void PublishSalesToRaven(IEnumerable<Sale> sales)
{
    sales.ForEach(session.Store);
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: the session you see is a wrapper on the IDocuentSession from Raven. The add calls the Store method. Commit calls SaveChanges. With your code, what happens when I do session.Store for a document that already exists in raven? will Raven be smart to understand that it needs to be updated and not added?

Comment: FWIW remember that ForEach is a nonstandard linq method, you either need code that implements yourself, some library that has it built in, or use a standard foreach block.

Comment: @afif - is this correct => if u have a new car sales, the Id == null? Otherwise, the Id is some number?

Comment: @Pure.Krome no actually. Because the Cars are coming from an existing store they always have an id. And I use the same Id to persist them to Raven.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me right now. Note: The InjectFrom method comes from Omu.ValueInjecter (nuget package)

```
    private void PublishSalesToRaven(IEnumerable<Sale> sales)
    {
        var ids = sales.Select(i => i.Id);
        var existingSales = _ravenSession.Load<Sale>(ids);
        existingSales.ForEach(s => s.InjectFrom(sales.Single(i => i.Id == s.Id)));

        var existingIds = existingSales.Select(i => i.Id);
        var nonExistingSales = sales.Where(i => !existingIds.Any(x => x == i.Id));
        nonExistingSales.ForEach(i => _ravenSession.Store(i));

        _ravenSession.SaveChanges();
    }
```